# Не запускается JavaFx приложение!

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Я собираю артифакт в intellij idea и он не запускается а если запускаю через терминал пишет вот ето что делать?

Терминал:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at sample.Main.start(Main.java:12)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

sample.Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root =        FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/main.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("MoreCalculate");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 270));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

MANIFEST:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sample.Main
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так как файловую структуру проекта вы в вопросе не предоставили, то наверняка сказать нельзя, но, скорее всего, дело в неправильном пути к _main.fxml_.

Comment: Я добавил картинку с структурой проекта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замени:

```
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/main.fxml"));
```

На:

```
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/main.fxml"));
```

Про сборку артифакта Java FX проекта здесь информация: [http://info.javarush.ru/iruslan/2014/03/20/Как-создать-файл-exe-в-intellij.html](http://info.javarush.ru/iruslan/2014/03/20/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-exe-%D0%B2-intellij.html)

Comment: Спасибо заработало!