# Путь к файлу загрузчиком FXMLLoader в Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Столкнулся в с распространенной проблемой - определение пути к xml.

Main.java:

```
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
```

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный вопрос аналогичен вопросам(по сути проблемы):

1. [Не запускается JavaFx приложение!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607604/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-javafx-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/607614#607614)
2. [Не открывается .jar (IDEA IntelliJ)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617417/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-jar-idea-intellij/617462#617462)

Однако они не помогают решить мою проблему. Как работает этот загрузчик?

Создание JAVA FX проекта с помощью MAVEN -  http://devcolibri.com/3264

Comment: сделайте минимальный запускаемый пример и добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, что ещё можно добавить в вопрос? Ваше решение подходит при создании Java FX проекта. Я создал Maven проект.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос pom и минимальный набор файлов, что бы можно было собрать проект и увидеть проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В пакете **sample**

```
public class Controller {
}


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Этот файл должен быть в **resources/sample**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>trash</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

После сборки jar его можно запустить

```
java -jar target/javafx-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Выложил полный код приложения на Github [JavaFX Maven Example](https://github.com/Vaysman/javafx-maven-example)

Comment: Я знаю, что так запустится на любом другом проекте. У меня Maven проект, ошибка все равно осталась

Comment: я добавил pom файл. и проверил - у меня работает.